# Big(O) for this algorithm

Tags: algorithm, big-o

What is the big(O) of this algorithm. 
I know that it is similar to O(log(n)) but instead of being halved each time, it is being shrunken exponentially.

```
sum = 0
i = n
j = 2 
while(i>=1) 
    sum = sum+i 
    i = i/j
    j = 2*j
```

Comment: What's your answer? Hint: many correct answers are possible (O(n^2), O(n^3) are some of them)

Comment: `:-O` <-- this is your Big O

Comment: @Henry I know that it is <O(logn) since it's being divided by 2, then 4, then 8 .... I just don't know how to express it as a logarithm.

Comment: It makes more sense to ask for the big-Theta, Another hint for that: investigate what happens to log2(i) in each step. How many steps are necessary to bring it down to 0?

Comment: So i know if  i = 2 , it takes 1 step, i = 8 it takes 2 steps, i = 64 it takes 3 steps, i = 1024, it takes 4 steps

Comment: correct. Another view: what is the result of summing the first k numbers (1+2+3+...+k), and what is 2^(1+2+3+...+k)?

Comment: Well sum of k numbers is k(k+1)/2, but I don't see the connection to this question.

Comment: Then evaluate 2^(1+2+3+..+k) for the first few k and compare to the i-values you got for 1, 2, 3, .. steps.

Comment: Woah, I see a pattern, I end up with k^2 + k = log2(n)*2, k being number of steps, but I don't know how to simplify it into a bigO formula.

Comment: Enough of spoon feeding; just solve the last formula for k, making some simplifications that are irrelevant if you just want the big-Theta.

Comment: Thanks Henry, so it's just log2(n) then

Comment: no. k^2 is approximately that, you want k.

Comment: so sqrt(log(n))

Answer (score 2):

The denominator `d` is

```
d := 2^(k * (k + 1) / 2)
```

in the k-th iteration of the loop. Thus you have to solve when `d` is larger than `n` which leads to a fraction less than 1

```
2^(k * (k + 1) / 2) > n
```

for `k` and fixed `n`. Inserting

```
solve 2^(k * (k + 1) / 2) > n for k
```

in WolframAlpha gives

[image]

Thus, you have a running time of `O(sqrt(log n))` for your algorithm, when you remove the irrelevant constants from the formula.